# Interrogating a cell to see whether any of the strings are present in a reference table

Tags: excel, vba

**Background:** I'm trying to Interrogate a cell to see whether any of the text strings (Names) within it are present in a reference table of text strings (Names) in another sheet.

I want to then return a Y or N depending on if any of the table strings are found in the cell

*Note:* Broking is a list i created which is the reference table.

**Current problem:**

It's pulling the found name from the string but i can't work how to add an expression that simply returns "Y" or "N" based on whether one of the strings in table is present in the cell

I've tried:

```
=IF(INDEX(Broking,SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Broking,AE7))*ROW($2:$8)),"Y", "N")
```

Comment: Does your current formula work?  That's a significant point missing from your post.  Regarding the discussion of "if VBA is a better option," that would be subjective and leading this post to be Closed due to being `Too Broad`.  Please ask objective questions, preferably related to issues in your specific coding example.

Comment: Looks like you just need to remove the `INDEX` function in that formula.

Comment: Thanks Tiger but that doesn't work - that means it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code, with some clarification in comment (example of data below) :

```
Sub StringsAttached()
    ' looks in each cell in sheet "Base" col A for any names in sheet "Broking"
    ' if found, writes 'Y' in sheet "Base" col B, 'N' if not found

    Dim TotalRows As Long       ' last row in sheet "Base"
    Dim StrToFind As Variant    ' will be an array
    Dim i As Integer            ' to iterate on each row of sheet "Base"
    Dim strToCheck As String    ' string to check
    Dim item As Variant         ' string from sheet "Broking"
    Dim ispresent As Integer    ' result of InStr (search in string)

    TotalRows = Sheets("Base").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    StrToFind = Worksheets("Broking").Range("A2:A6") ' range with brokers names

    For i = 2 To TotalRows  ' Loop 1: iterates each row, omitting heading row (1)
        strToCheck = Sheets("Base").Range("A" & i)
        For Each item In StrToFind  ' Loop 2: look for each broker names in turn
            ispresent = InStr(strToCheck, item)  ' search in string
            If ispresent <> 0 Then
                Sheets("Base").Range("B" & i) = "Y"
                GoTo exitWhenFound  ' when one name is found, exit Loop 2
            Else
                Sheets("Base").Range("B" & i) = "N"
            End If
        Next item
exitWhenFound:
    Next

End Sub
```

I have two sheets in a workbook, "Base" and "Broking".

In "Base", the table looks like this :

```
Strings to check            Yes or No
John, Paul, George, Ringo   Y
Harry, Hermione, Ron        N
Doug, Vanessa, Jim, Claire  Y
Vanessa, Claire             N
Ornella, Renzo, Alberto     N
Renzo, Ornella              N
Tim, Bruno, Doug            Y
Mary, Renzo                 Y
Jean, Pierre, Donald        N
Jim, Jean, Bruno            Y
Renzo, Mike Johnson         Y
Ornella, Mike Smith         N
```

And in sheet "Broking" :

```
Names
Doug
Jim
Mary
John
Mike Johnson
```

Comment: I'm not sure- I'm having difficulty getting it to reference the Rows in the Broking sheet rather than the current sheet. I've tried the usual but it's not liking it.

Comment: Can you give examples of the content of the cells to interrogate, and of the text strings in the reference table? And what should match or not match? Also, you have used the "vba" tag, have you tried a vba code? if so, can you show us the code and where exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: Hi Panda, I used VBA to simply enter the formula and copy it down to the last row. Thats easy enough and that bit works. Example of a cell: "John, Tim Doug Jim", Table is simply a list of all the broker names in a column "Hardy, Doug, Jim". I'm trying to get it to return a Y if the cells contains one of the names in the broker name table

Comment: I don't see how to do this with a formula. However, I will edit my answer with a vba code that seems to do the job. Just let me know whether it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your 'broking' is a Named Range, you can use this formula
I'm interrogating cell 'C2' here

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(broking, C2)), "Y","N")
```

Comment: No i tried this. Returns a "N" when it should return a "Y"

Comment: It worked for me, even when the strings in 'broking' were substrings of the items in the cell.